# Transactions per second in Jmeter not showing the exact value

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins

I have written a Jmeter script with 10 threads and 100 loops. So basically, it's 1000 samples. If you look at the Transactions per second PNG, it's approximately 1 transaction in 1 second. [image]

Looking at the Bytes per Second, it's a big figure. Why is that?

[image]

What's the relation between these two images? I am bit confused here. Can someone put some light here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have 1000 samples in 15 minutes, 15 minutes == 900 seconds so it is absolutely expected that throughput would be something like 1 transaction per second.

Bytes per second is basically the size of response data you are getting, looking into the graph it appears that you are receiving around 300 kilobytes for each request.

If you need to apply more load - [increase number of virtual users](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/build-web-test-plan.html#adding_users) (threads) and decrease ramp-up time, you should be seeing higher throughput (given your server can handle this load, otherwise it will be the bottleneck).

See [JMeter Test Results: Why the Actual Users Number is Lower than Expected](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-test-results-why-actual-users-number-lower-expected) article to get more understanding on how does JMeter work in terms of applying the load.

Comment: Thanks Dmitri for the help.